# Next JS 14 createContext updates doesn't update State correclty

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I am quite new to createContext within ReactJS and I am struggling to set a State which I want to use in a Child Component.

I have two Interfaces which look like this:

```
export interface Schema {
    database: string;
    name: string;
    models: Model[];
}

export interface Model {
    name: string;
}
```

My State Provider looks like this:

```
'use client';

import {Model, Schema} from '@/utils/types';
import {createContext, Dispatch, ReactNode, useContext, useEffect, useReducer} from 'react';

interface AppState {
    schema: Schema;
    schemaId: string;
}

type Action = | { type: 'SET_SCHEMA', payload: { schema: Schema, schemaId: string } }

const initialState: AppState = {
    schema: {
        database: 'postgresql',
        models: [],
        name: ''
    },
    schemaId: ""
}

const appReducer = (state: AppState = initialState, action: Action): AppState => {
    console.log({state, action})
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_SCHEMA":
            return {
                ...state,
                schema: action.payload.schema,
                schemaId: action.payload.schemaId
            }
    }
}

const AppStateContext = createContext<| { state: AppState; dispatch: Dispatch<Action> } | undefined>(undefined);

interface AppStateProvider {
    children: ReactNode;
}

const AppStateProvider = ({children}: AppStateProvider) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('State changed ', state);
    }, [state]);

    return (
        <AppStateContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
            {children}
        </AppStateContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default AppStateProvider;

export const useAppState = () => {
    const context = useContext(AppStateContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useAppState must be used within an AppStateProvider');
    }

    return context;
}
```

I am fetching the Record from Postgres SQL and in there I have a JSON Field which I want to convert to the Interface Schema and then Dispatching the Action "SET_SCHEMA". This looks like this (I didn't provide the Action to fetch it because it's coming from the Parent Component):

```
    const {state, dispatch} = useAppState();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(schema.schema)
        const newSchema = schema.schema as unknown as Schema;
        dispatch({
            type: 'SET_SCHEMA',
            payload: {
                schema: {
                    name: newSchema.name,
                    database: "postgresql",
                    enums: newSchema.enums,
                    models: newSchema.models
                },
                schemaId: schema.id
            }
        });
    }, [schema]);
```

Later I want to add more Actions so that I can update the Schema. But for now I want to set the State correctly.

I have tried to adjust the Code based on other Resources but until now I didn't find any useful Information for that. The last State change contains an empty Schema Object whereas it should contain the State I previously set. I also checked my Code if I dispatch the same action somewhere else but this is not the Case.